# Clicking a text link - Using Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The link that I am trying to click is not being recognized at all. Developer tools in chrome shows me the link as in structure below:

```
<main 
   <div
    <ifreame
     #document
      <html
        <body
          <form
             <div
                 ::before
                   <a href=wizard_view.do?  sys_action=sysverb_wizard_ans&WIZARD:action=follow&wiz_referring_url=&wiz_collection_key=&wiz_collectionID=&wiz_collection=&wiz_collection_related_field=&wiz_view=&wiz_action=sysverb_new&sys_id=ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0&sysparm_query=active=true&sysparm_target=&sys_target=change_ddfdff>Standard (from Template)

 </a>
 ::after
 </div>
  ....
```

How do I identify and click this particular text link?I tried css selector,xpath etc but didn't work

```
 anchors = dd.findElements(By.linkText(Standard (from Template)));      

 anchors2 =          dd.findElements(By.cssSelector(a[href*='ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0'] )));
```

Also there are a 10 div sections with same class name each of which is a text link. I want to click on of them (see above)

Comment: thats invalid html?

Comment: you've misspelled iframe..

Comment: Not sure, but  it does look like you may want to try with 'sys_action' instead of href ? In your second selector !! Like: a[sys_action*='ea7d96126f92a100f3ae60526e3ee4e0']

Comment: @rahul raj, Add exact `HTML` code as provided one is definitely broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to search for elements inside an iframe, you have to switch to that frame first

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("_the_frame_id")))
```

Comment: You've missed one closing bracket

Comment: Also you might need to add code for case when there is no `id`/`name` set to `iframe` (quite common case)

Comment: After changing the case of Frame to frame and Switch to switch and FindElement to findElement in your line of code, it worked perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @rahulraj using upper/lower case depends on which languages you use, since you tag c#, I wrote the code with uppercase. But I'm glad it could help.

Comment: @LinhNguyen - Is there any other elements like iframe which needs special treatment like this

Comment: So far I know that you need to switch to iframe, alert, new window. You can read more here https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html

Comment: I have a text input box in the next page after this which is under the same frame . There when I try to access the inputbox it says 'NosuchElementException' I tried having switchtoframe line of code before that again. Then that line also fails with same message on the console

Comment: Try `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` and then start to locate the text box again

Comment: No luck . I could see that the id and name attribute of input tag(see below answer I posted) are changing each time the page loads. Is there a way to handle this. Was trying css selector input[id$='_text']  as it always ends with '_input '- But I don't know the usage if this to get the element

Comment: WebElement stTemplate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-  control"));  -- This worked .

Answer (score 0):

Switching to frame solved my issue . But in the next page also I have the same freme (id/name) and I am not able to identify an input text box even though I have already switched to the frame.

[image]

I am getting 'NoSuchElementException' when:

```
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("gsft_main")));
      WebElement stdFromTemplate = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Standard  (from Template)"));

stdFromTemplate.click();
WebElement stTemplate =   driver.findElement(By.id("cced8819db987e08dee9f7b31d961989_text"));
```

This last line(which is a new page now after clicking on the link that i was mentioning in the initial question) line give me 'NoSuchElementFoundException'